# java: breadth first traversal with backtracking for maze

Tags: java, breadth-first-search, maze

I am trying to implement a **breadth first traversal** for a maze. This is the code I have so far using a linked list but I am not sure if it is searching breadth first. Is this the proper way to do it? any suggestions, comments?

```
    public boolean traverseBreadth(){
    //traverse the floor from entrance to exit
    //stepping only on red tiles
    steps = new LinkedList<Tile>();
    possibleSteps = new LinkedList<Tile>();
     //reset markings
     reset();
    //push the entrance onto the stack
    entrance.setVisited();
    steps.add(entrance);

    System.out.println("add " + entrance);
    nextMoves(entrance);
    //keep going as long as we have a possibility to move
    //and we haven't reached the end yet
    while (!possibleSteps.isEmpty()&& (!possibleSteps.getLast().equals(exit)))
    {   
        Tile x = possibleSteps.removeLast();

        x.setMarked();   //walked on that square
        steps.add(x);  //walk to that square
        System.out.println("Walked to the square  " + x);
        //now figure out where you can walk from this square
        nextMoves(x);
        try {
               Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
               }
             catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               }





    }
    if (possibleSteps.getLast().equals(exit)){
        steps.push(possibleSteps.removeLast());
        System.out.println("made it from entrance to exit");
        System.out.println(steps.toString());
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"sorry can't reach the exit");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: did you get this working? Do you mind sharing the final version of your code? I need exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a breadth first search - this is depth first.

There are 2 places that are obviously depth first

- you remove from the end of the frontier (possibleTiles), not the beginning.
- you do not have a traversal hierarchy (parent to child) to rebuild the traversal path, only a single "path" with tiles. Therefore, it is depth first.

Things to change:

- instead of LinkedList, change that to Dictionary. The key of the dictionary will be the tile, and the value will be the tile's parent. Use this to reconstruct your final path.
- your "moveNext" function is probably right. Make sure it is pushing to the end of the List.
- do not pop (getLast()) from PossibleSteps. PossibleSteps should be a First-In-First-Out queue. Retrieve the first Tile of PossibleSteps (this will explore the tiles closest to the start first).

Things to improve:

- instead of using Tile to track exploration, use a Set (call it ExploredTile) where you put tiles that you have traversed)
- use a Queue instead of List.

Some C#/Pseudo Code (cuz I'm not at an IDE)

```
Dictionary<Tile,Tile> path = ...;
Queue<Tile> frontier = ...;
Set<Tile> explored = ...;

path[start] = null;

while(frontier.Count > 0){
    var tile = frontier.Dequeue();

    if(explored.Contains(tile)){
        continue;
    }
    explored.add(tile);

    if (Tile == Exit){
        rebuildPath(Exit);
    }else{
        for (Tile t in Tile.neighbours){
            if (!explored.Contains(t)){
                frontier.Enqueue(t);
                path[t] = tile; // Set the path hierarchy
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RebuildPath

```
LinkedList<Tile> finalPath = ...;

Tile parent = path[exitTile];
finalPath.push(exitTile);

while(parent != null){
    finalPath.push(parent);
    parent = path[parent];
}

finalPath.reverse();
```

Hopefully I got it right... :)